# Relation between TPM Command Reference and TSS

Tags: security, interface, tpm

The TCG offers two different specifications of commands/interfaces for developers of a middleware that communicates with a TPM. There is on the one hand the TPM Command Reference as described in

http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/static_page_files/72C33D71-1A4B-B294-D02C7DF86630BE7C/TPM%20Main-Part%203%20Commands_v1.2_rev116_01032011.pdf

and on the other hand the TSS as described in

http://www.trustedcomputinggroup.org/files/resource_files/6479CD77-1D09-3519-AD89EAD1BC8C97F0/TSS_1_2_Errata_A-final.pdf.

The latter one copes with different interface specifications for different layers (TDDL, TCS, TSP) whereas the former one describes functions that should be build upon the device driver.

As an example compare the TSS TDDL interface to the commands specified in the TPM Command Reference:

**TSS TDDLI:**

- Tddli_Open()
- Tddli_Close()
- Tddli_Cancel()
- Tddli_GetCapability()
- Tddli_SetCapability()
- Tddli_GetStatus()
- Tddli_TransmitData()

**TPM Command Reference:**

- TPM_Init()
- TPM_TakeOwnership()
- TPM_GetCapability()
- TPM_MigrateKey()
- ...

Trousers e.g. implements the full TSS whereas other libraries as libtpm only implement some functions of the TPM Command Reference.

What is the relationship between this two interface specifications?

Answer (score 1):

The **TPM Command** and **TPM Structures** documents only specifies what a TPM has to do.

- Which commands are implemented on the TPM
- How do the inputs look like
- How the commands issued to the TPM are authenticated
- How does the TPM react to such inputs
- How does the response look like

The **TSS** on the other hand provides an API for application developers to conviniently develop trust enabled applications. Parts of the TSS don't even issue commands to the TPM, like the key storage part or user management.

In the TSS document you linked you have a structured view of the stack in Figure 1-1 on page 30. The TPM Command reference specifies how the thin line between *TSS Device Driver Library* and the *TPM* looks like. The TSS Specification on the other hand specifies how the *Tddli interface*, the *TCS interface* and the *TSP interface* look like.

If you prefer analogies, let's compare it to HTTP: The former would be similar to the HTTP specification, while the TSS is more like a API documentation of a HTTP client library. An application developer usually does not open a socket and starts to send `GET / HTTP/1.0 ...` over the wire. She uses a library instead and focuses on higher levels of abstraction. Likewise, you usually don't assemble TPM commands bit by bit, but use the TSS instead.